# Building tensorflow 1.10 succeeded but package installation fails

Tags: tensorflow, build, ubuntu-16.04

I try to build tensorflow 1.10 with cuda from a python3 virtual environment :

- ./configure succeeded
- first step build with bazel succeeded ([with the necessity to install additional things](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21518#issuecomment-411875069))

  $ bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

At first time the build failed:

```
import keras_applications
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_applications'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 9114.151s, Critical Path: 335.72s
INFO: 6696 processes: 6696 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

But after having installed some keras components and h5py:

```
pip install keras_applications==1.0.4 --no-deps
Collecting keras_applications==1.0.4
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/90/8f327deaa37a71caddb59b7b4aaa9d4b3e90c0e76f8c2d1572005278ddc5/Keras_Applications-1.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 633kB/s 
Installing collected packages: keras-applications
Successfully installed keras-applications-1.0.4
(DeepFish) jeanpat@Dell-T5500:~/Developpement/Arch-TensorFlow/tensorflow$ pip install keras_preprocessing==1.0.2 --no-deps
Collecting keras_preprocessing==1.0.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/26/1e778ebd737032749824d5cba7dbd3b0cf9234b87ab5ec79f5f0403ca7e9/Keras_Preprocessing-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: keras-preprocessing
Successfully installed keras-preprocessing-1.0.2
(DeepFish) jeanpat@Dell-T5500:~/Developpement/Arch-TensorFlow/tensorflow$ pip install h5py==2.8.0
Collecting h5py==2.8.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/cb/726134109e7bd71d98d1fcc717ffe051767aac42ede0e7326fd1787e5d64/h5py-2.8.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.8MB 1.9MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in /home/jeanpat/anaconda3/envs/DeepFish/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from h5py==2.8.0) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/jeanpat/anaconda3/envs/DeepFish/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from h5py==2.8.0) (1.11.0)
keras-applications 1.0.4 has requirement keras>=2.1.6, but you'll have keras 2.0.8 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: h5py
  Found existing installation: h5py 2.7.1
    Uninstalling h5py-2.7.1:
      Successfully uninstalled h5py-2.7.1
Successfully installed h5py-2.8.0
```

It was possible to finish the build:

```
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package
INFO: Elapsed time: 55.947s, Critical Path: 29.05s
INFO: 40 processes: 40 local.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 43 total actions
```

- second step build succeeded too with some warnings:

  $ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
  jeudi 23 août 2018, 15:02:24 (UTC+0200) : === Preparing sources in dir: /tmp/tmp.dEwVvSzrd0
  ~/Developpement/Arch-TensorFlow/tensorflow ~/Developpement/Arch-TensorFlow/tensorflow
  ~/Developpement/Arch-TensorFlow/tensorflow
  jeudi 23 août 2018, 15:02:31 (UTC+0200) : === Building wheel

  warning: no files found matching '*.pd' under directory '*'

  warning: no files found matching '*.dll' under directory '*'

  warning: no files found matching '*.lib' under directory '*'

  warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'tensorflow/include/tensorflow'

  warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/Eigen'

  warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'tensorflow/include/google'

  warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/third_party'

  warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tensorflow/include/unsupported'

  jeudi 23 août 2018, 15:03:09 (UTC+0200) : === Output wheel file is in: /tmp/tensorflow_pkg

Finally I tried to install the python package:

```
$ pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.10.0-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement '/tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.10.0-py2-none-any.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
tensorflow-1.10.0-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Answer (score 0):

Package installation succeeded with:

```
$ pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow*.whl
```